# Drupal 7 hook_node_view remove Views generated content

Tags: drupal-7, view, nodes, alter

I have a need to programmatically remove an image field on a node display.

To achieve this my module implements **hook_node_view** and I can unset data in **$node->content** which prevents it from displaying on the node page.
However, because Views generates the image, it is not represented in **$node->content**.

**Can anyone suggest a solution that will allow me to remove Views generated content from a module?**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Views** to generate your node, I'll suggest you to unset your field in `template_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)` where you can access it via `$vars['view']->result` which is an array with all the rows displayed in your view. Then you can search for your field in each row and unset it.

Example for a image field structure:

```
function template_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  foreach($vars['view']->result as $test){
    $test->field_field_image[0]['rendered']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. As much as it DOES help, it removes the view across the entire site. I only need it to remove it on specific nodes. As there is no node data I can't check

Comment: If the specific nodes are related to a specific content-type, it wouldn't be a problem to check. If it is random however, you have no choice but check for each nid. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @justinelejeune for her efforts, I found a simpler solution.

Implementing **hook_node_view**, you can just unset the target field or set the field array to blank I.E:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode){
    if( $view_mode != 'full')
        return;

  unset($node->field_banner); // or     $node->field_banner = array();

}
```